# Nginx 403 while accessing static files in docker volumes

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-volume

I am trying to serve static files in docker volumes for my Django project.  Nginx is able to access the files(403) error. I tried to solve this in different ways like updating the file permission. Nginx I am  installed in a normal way without a container and Django, Postgres database is running in a container

Nginx configuration

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 139.59.73.115;

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }

        location /static {
                root /var/lib/docker/volumes/m3-mobiles_m3-mobiles-assets/_data/;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think need changed:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name 139.59.73.115;
  rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;

  location / {
    root  /var/www/html/;
    autoindex on;
  }
  location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }
}
```

On run docker the containe map your path location:  /home/xxxxx/xxxx:/var/www/html/